# How to remove numbers from strings?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I had a mission to just print in reverse the firstname and lastname that the user is inputting.
working fine but I tried through import re, and re.sub to just delete any numbers if the user mistakely inputting numbers inside and it just not working.

Here is the code:

```
import re

firstname = input("enter first name:")
lastname = input("enter last name:")
firstname = re.sub('1-9', '', firstname)
lastname = re.sub('1-9', '', lastname)
print(lastname, firstname)
```

What is the problem in here?

Comment: `re.sub('[0-9]', '', firstname)` and `re.sub('[0-9]', '', lastname)` should do the trick, you have to wrap it inside of `[]`

Comment: _it just not working_ isn't helpful at all. What IS the problem? Does the program crash? - provide tracelog. Output not as expected? - post sample input, output, and expected output. See [ask].

Comment: I just said, i am new to stackoverflow, nothing happend if i asked first time little bit wrongly.
and i asked right because i didnt got any problem no crash and nothing it just didnt worked first without the []

Comment: @newtopythonXD No problem, you can just take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **Friendly reminder**: You forgot to accept the answer. Also, you can delete the answer you posted.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish please stop soliciting the OP to accept your answer (or any answer). They are not obligated to do so

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `'1-9'` will match the string `1-9`. If you want to specify a set of characters, you should enclose it with `[]`:

```py
print(re.sub('[1-9]', '', 'Name 1with 12numbers'))
# >> Name with numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `\d+` to remove digits:

```
import re
firstname = input("enter first name:")
lastname = input("enter last name:")
firstname = re.sub('\d+', '', firstname)
lastname = re.sub('\d+', '', lastname)
print(lastname, firstname)
```

Or use `[0-9]`:

```
import re
firstname = input("enter first name:")
lastname = input("enter last name:")
firstname = re.sub('[0-9]', '', firstname)
lastname = re.sub('[0-9]', '', lastname)
print(lastname, firstname)
```

Output:

```
enter first name:Hello12
enter last name:World23
World Hello
```